Generating a TTL signal triggered by the falling edge of another TTL signal
I have a power supply that can produce pulses up to a switching frequency of 100 kHz. The power supply has an external TTL signal interface that produces TTL signal corresponding to the level of output pulses. When the voltage output is zero, the TTL signal generated from the supply is low (0), when the output is high, the generated TTL from the pulsar is high (1).
I want to trigger another active circuit (MOSFET-based) for a fixed period (within 50-500 ns range) at the falling edge of the TTL signal, i.e, when the output is going to zero. To trigger the MOSFET-based active circuit I need a TTL signal which is triggered at the falling edge of the output pulse/TTL signal generated from the power supply.

How I can use the external TTL signal generated by the power supply, to create another fixed-width TTL signal to activate the MOSFET-based circuit? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

It would help if you provide a schematic or a photo of your hand-drawing of what you currently have or of the idea that you have in mind.

@EdinFifić, A picture has been added to the post. Hope it helps to better explain my query.

The desired accuracy/tolerance of the width of the pulse, the minimum delay tolerated for the rising edge, and the amount of jitter allowed on the falling edge is going to greatly influence the solution. Consider adding those specs to the question.

The circuit you want is called a monostable multivibrator, or just a monostable.  In your case you want it to trigger on the negative edge of its input signal, and produce a positive output pulse.
How accurate or repeatable does the output pulse width have to be?
Also, do you want the output pulse to be anything in the 50-500 ns range, or a specific value, or an adjustable value, or other - ?
Please update your question with this information.
There are many ways to do this, from transistors to opamps to TTL, CMOS, and ECL gates.  At your speeds, a 555 will not work.  You can search for 'monostable circuit' or monostable schematic' (without the quotes) to see lotsa examples.
I would start with AC-series CMOS gates such as the 74AC132.  There are 4 gates in one package, and your circuit will take three of them - two gates to form the pulse, and one gate to invert it to the correct logic polarity.
Schematic later.
